# How to evaluate a template from a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I've got this template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="product in ad.products">
      <a href="{{product.link}}">
        <h1>{{product.title}}</h1>
        <img src="{{product.src}}">
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <h5>{{product.price}}</h5>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From my controller I need to evaluate this template so that it checks how many products that have been selected and then it interpolates each product's values into the template. After that is done I also need to remove the ng-repeat so it doesn't fire an error in the external pages that will use this where angular is not present. However I'd figure that I'd just use a regex to look up the `ng-repeat` and everything in the expression and then remove it.

I've been looking at `$interpolate` and `$compile` but I can't figure out how to work with them from my controller so that it does what I want. This is because when I use these on my template and then console log the template value it's a function with a whole lot of nonsense in it.

So doing this:

```
ad.html = $compile(res.data, $scope);
```

Generates something like this:

```
function(b,c,d){rb(b,"scope");e&&e.needsNewScope&&(b=b.$parent.$new());d=d||{};var h=d.parentBoundTranscludeFn,k=d.transcludeControllers;d=d.futureParentElement;h&&h.$$boundTransclude&&(h=h.$$boundTr…
```

Can someone shed some light on how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using $compile function in wrong way, you should call `$compile(html)` function by passing `$scope` parameter like below.

```
var compiledDOM = $compile(res.data)($scope);//then do append this DOM to wherever you want
ad.html = compiledDOM.html(); //but this HTML would not make angular binding working.
```

Comment: Ok that seems to compile it, but how to I get an html snippet rather than a DOM object from that? It also spits out a lot of root infinite digest errors.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz may I know why you need that, because taking html part of it would not make angular binding workable ? though its possible by having `compiledDOM.html()` OR `compiledDOM[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Because I need to send the snippet to backend which will then store it and use it as static HTML. But I'm not sure how to get the snippet because like you said it doesn't evaluate the angular bindings then.. hm.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz no..it will have all the records rendered by `ng-repeat`, but once you takeout `html` from the compiled DOM, you will get that HTML & you will have raw DOM(simple HTML, example, that will not fire `ng-click` event even if ng-click is bouded to it.), is it clear now?

Comment: But I just tried with both .innerhtml and html() and I just get the raw html before any bindings have been evaluated. But I think I've found a solution which waits for the digest cycle to finish running before setting ad.html to the evaluated html. So your solution works.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz you could wrap out this inside `$timeout` function, which will evaluate expression, one digest cycle later,

Comment: Ye that's what I did.